# How to pass a parameter to create a variable in js?

Tags: javascript, function, class, parameters

I am trying to work with javascript, classes, and threejs to make a project. I have an idea to have a singular function create a new threejs object, but not sure how to implement it.

Let me go a bit more in detail. I have a class that creates a cube using threejs:

```
class Cube {
  constructor(geometry, material, /*position variables*/, scene) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
    this.material = material;
    /* this.positions */
  }
  createMesh() {
    //creates a mesh for the cube
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.materials );
  }
  addToScene() {
      this.scene.add( this.mesh );

      /* changes position with variables */
  }

}
```

This class works nicely, but I am wanting to create a new function that makes a unique cube, and with a custom variable. **I want to create something like this:**

```
var createCube = function ( name, geometry, material, /*position*/, scene) {
    name = new Cube(geometry, material, /*position*/, scene;
}
```

Then after I use this function, I can use the name in the parameter as such:

```
createCube( customName, cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial, /*position*/, threeScene);
customName.createMesh();
customName.addToScene();
```

I realize I can always hard code the name for the cube, however, I will be passing it through loops to create multiple. 
I gave a lot of explanation for a likely simple solution, but I hope this helps give a picture of what I am trying to do. If you need more explanation, I am open to do so.

Comment: If you need to make multiple, put them all in an array.

Comment: I mean passing them through a for loop in order to create multiple, and for what I am doing an array would not be as efficient.

Comment: Either an array or an object is the way to hold dynamically created objects.

Comment: You really should just `return` the new cube value, and use  `const customName = createCube(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial, /*position*/, threeScene);`. Please show us the loop that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this dynamically is to create an array and push an object to it. I got a similar output when working with node applications.

```js
var cubesArray = []

function createCube(name, geometry, material, /*position*/, scene) {
let thisCube = new Cube(geometry, material, /*position*/, scene);
cubesArray[name] = thisCube;
}
```

Now we can do all the functions and access properties with: cubesArray[*name*].*property* or cubesArray[*name*].*function*()

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem here. I might be missing something.

If a `Cube` needs to be identified by `name`, could you add it as a property of the `Cube`?

```js
class Cube {
  constructor(name, /* other properties */) {
    this.name = name;
    /* other properties */
  }
  createMesh() {
  }
  addToScene() {
  }
}

const names = ['cube1', 'cube2', 'cube3'];
const cubes = names.map(name => new Cube(name, geometry, material, /*position*/, scene));

cubes.forEach(cube => {
  console.log(`cube: ${cube.name}`);
  cube.createMesh();
  cube.addToScene();
});
```

Comment: This is a better way of doing what I need to do as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, JS does not allow passing references as method arguments.
What you want to eventually achieve is unclear to me, here is my attempt to have custom named cubes on a `cubesObject`.

```
const cubesObject = {};
for (const name of ['a', 'b', 'c']) {
  cubesObject[name] = new Cube(geometry, material, /* position */, scene);
}
console.log(cubesObject.a, cubesObject.b, cubesObject.c)
```